# Marionette.Layout onBeforeClose called before Regions are closed?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I've got a Marionette.Layout that manages a bunch of region sub-views that contain information I'd like to save before the user navigates away from the page. I was using `onBeforeClose()` in the Layout, but the regions seem to be closed and removed before the Layout is. Further, it doesn't seem like returning `false` in `onBeforeClose()` can prevent destruction of sub-views either. Any thoughts on whether there is an alternative approach or whether Marionette's `onBeforeClose()` should be called earlier?

Others have suggested detecting changes before the close happens, but as mentioned here ([Prevent Marionette view from close onBeforeClose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652388/prevent-marionette-view-from-close-onbeforeclose)) it doesn't capture all the close cases.

Answer (score 0):

I usually end up writing my own `close` method when I need to change the default behavior. I'll create a mixin if it's going to be reusable.  Something like:

```
close: function() {
    if (this.isClosed){ return; }
    // the following if statement is the only difference between
    // Marionette.Layout.close and my view's version.
    // Everything in the if is original
    if ( myCondition ) {
        this.regionManager.close();
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
        Marionette.ItemView.prototype.close.apply(this, args);
    }
}
```

It's not necessarily what you were looking for, but it is an option. `onBeforeClose` is called from `Marionette.View.close`, which in turn is called from `ItemView.close`. This is the only way I've found to get the control I'm looking for.

Comment: Hm, I guess overriding Marionette would be an option... not so desirable. Are there reasons why onBeforeClose for a Layout shouldn't be called before the regions get closed? It would be the only way of allowing onBeforeClose to return false to stop the close process.